# Multiple String Delimiters in StringTokenizer

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I am tokenizing an HTML block which has to be split by these whole tag strings:

```
<dd>
</dd>
<dt>
</dt>
```

I can't specify

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(block,"<dt></dt><dd></dd>");
st.nextToken();
```

These aren't a collection of chars, it's a collection of whole strings. Is there an elegant way to tokenize this?

Comment: Yes. The solution below worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html):

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility
>   reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended
>   that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String
>   or the java.util.regex package instead.

So, if you have a `String block` that contains the data to tokenize. Do something like

```
String[] tokens = block.split("(<dd>)|(</dd>)|(<dt>)|(</dt>)");
```

and then your tokens will be the elements in the array `tokens`